# Header cell value assign to child cell value is not reflecting after changing the child value

Tags: excel

In Excel I have a cell (`N15`) and three more cells (`N20, N21, N22`). Here in Excel if I assign any value to N15 this should reflect in `N20, N21, N22` cells(`=N15`). I can change the child values also, after changing the child values if I change the header value it is not reflecting in changed child cell.

For instance, `N15= 10` then `N20=10, N21=10, N22=10` if I change the `(child)N20 =15` and again changing the Header Value N15 =18 than it is showing `N20=15, N21=18, N22=18` but expected is `N20=18,N21=18 ,N22=18.`

How to achieve this in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the worksheet's name tab and choose **View Code**. When the VBE opens up, paste the following into the pane titled something like *Book1 - Sheet1 (Code)*,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N15")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit:
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("N20:N22").Formula = "=N$15"
    End If

bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to return to your worksheet. If you put a value into N15, N20:N22 will receive the formula `=N$15`. You can overwrite the formula in any of those three cells but if you change the value in N15, the formula will go back into the three cells.

Comment: Where i should add this code.Can you please guide me.

Comment: If you are not going to bother reading what I've already typed, what sense does it make to retype it here?